Optimal strategy in a game where Doubling and Doubling+Reversing are the allowed moves
Recently, i've been interested in a $1$-player game. Your goal is to reach the smallest number that can be reached by $n$ moves of applying either $x \rightarrow 2x$ or $x\rightarrow R(2x)$. ($R(x)$ is the digit reversal function, for example, $R(512) = 215$) The optimal final value with $n$ moves (i.e. the smallest  number that can be reach with $n$ application of either  $x \rightarrow 2x$ or $x\rightarrow R(2x)$, with initial value of $1$) can be found in https://oeis.org/A371880 (actually, the draft edits aren't accepted yet, as of April 15 2024, so the sequence and discussions about it can be found at https://oeis.org/draft/A371880). The first few terms of the sequence are:
$$ 
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 23, 46, 29, 58, 71, 34, 68, 37, 47, 49, 89, 79, 59, 19, 38, 67, 35, 7, 14, 28, 56, 13...$$
Calculating the $n$-th term is actually very computationally expensive requiring $O(2^n)$ time. Sir Michael Branicky then came and calculated the optimal moves for $27≤n≤34$ and he found that $1$ can be reached again in $30$ moves and here is that combination that attain $1$ again:
$$1, 2, 4, 8, 61, 122, 442, 488, 976, 2591, 2815, 365, 37, 47, 49, 98, 196, 392, 487, 479, 859, 1718, 3436, 2786, 2755, 155, 13, 26, 25, 5, 1$$
Basically, Sir Branicky proved that $a(30k) = 1$ and $a(k) ≤ a(k \bmod 30) ≤ a(15) = 89$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. ($a(n)$ is the smallest number that can be achieved in the game with you having $n$ moves)
Can anybody prove/disprove the claim that the sequence of optimal final values (with $(k+1)$-thmember corresponding with the optimal final value given $k$ moves) is periodic?
The number $2718$ is an interesting number as there's a path of length $2$ from $2718$ to itself (doubling move followed by a doubling+reversing move). If one can find an odd length and an even length paths from 1 to itself, that both goes through $2718$, then this would prove that the sequence would eventually be all $1$s. Proving the claim once and for all.
(UPDATE: Actually, there's another path from $2718$ to itself that contains $7$ moves. So actually, a single path from $1$ to $1$ containing $2718$ would suffice)

Please define in the question what "optimal final values" are.  Please define what the function $a(\cdot)$ represents.

@D.W. I defined them already as the smallest number that can be achieved by n steps of applying either $n \rightarrow 2n$ or $n \rightarrow R(2n)$. But ohh, i forgot to add that the initial value is 1

Please define what "optimal final values" means, in the question, and what you mean by "the sequence of ...".

There can be no path starting from $1$ that reaches $2718$.  Note that $\ y\equiv R(y)\pmod{3}\ $ so the remainders mod $3$ of the terms in any path starting from $1$ must alternate between $1$ and $2$ and can never be $0$. Since $2718$ is divisible by $3$, it can't appear in any path starting from $1$. Also $x$ is divisible by $11$ if and only if $2x$ and $R(2x)$ are divisible by $11$, so no multiple of $11$ can appear in any path starting from $1$ either.

For $\ k\ne9\ $ , $\ a(k)\ $ is the minimum of the positive residues mod $99$ of $\ 2^k\ $ and $\ 10\times2^k\ ,$ which satisfies $\ a(k+30)=a(k)\ $ for $\ k\ne9\ .$ Thus, the sequence is ultimately periodic with period $30$. Its first $60$ terms, $\ a(0)$ to $a(59)\  $ are given by
\begin{array}{cc}1,2,4,8,16,23,46,29,58,\color{red}{71},34,68,37,47,49,\\89,79,59,19,38,67,35,7,14,28,56,13,25,5\\1,2,4,8,16,23,46,29,58,\color{red}{17},34,68,37,47,49,\\89,79,59,19,38,67,35,7,14,28,56,13,25,5\ .
\end{array}
The key observation from which this result follows is:

For every $\ k\in\Bbb{N}\ $ either $\ a(k)\equiv2^k\pmod{99}\ $ or $\ a(k)\equiv10\times2^k\pmod{99}\ .$

A proof of this isn't difficult, and I'll give one below.  Its consequences are that $\ a(k)\ $ can't be smaller than smallest of the positive residues mod $99$ of $\ 2^k\ $ and $\ 10\times2^k\ ,$ so if we can find a sequence of length $\ k\ $ starting from $\ 1\ $ and ending at the smallest such residue then that residue must be the value of $\ a(k)\ .$  It turns out that for every $\ k=0,1,2,\dots,59\ $ except $\ k=9\ $ such a sequence can be found, and therefore that for every such $\ k\ $ $\ a(k)\ $ is the smaller of the two residues $\ 2^k\pmod{99}\ $ and $\ 10\times2^k\pmod{99}\ $ that lie between $1$ and $98$. Fragments of the sequences needed to reach each of these residues are given in columns $2$ to $9$ of the table below.  In any column each successive term is obtained either by doubling or by doubling and reversing its immediate predecessor.  The first numbers in columns $3$ to $9$ are the reversals of another number earlier in the same row, and their immediate predecessors as the same as those of their reversals.
The smallest number in each row is listed in the tenth column.  Since there's a valid sequence of length equal to the number $\ k\ $  listed in the first column of the row, and leading from $1$ to the value listed in the tenth column, that value must  therefore be an upper bound for the value of $\ a(k)\ .$ The smallest positive residues mod $99$ of $\ 2^k\ $ and $\ 10\times2^k\ $ are listed in the eleventh and twelfth columns.  In every case, except $\ k=9\ ,$ the smaller of those two residues is equal to the value in the tenth column, which must therefore be the actual value of $\ a(k)\ .$
For $\ k=9\ $ there are only $\ 24\ $ numbers reachable from $1$ in $\ 9\ $ steps$,^\color{red}{\dagger}$ the smallest of which is $71$, so it follows that $\ a(9)=71\ .$
If $\ j=30n+k\ $ with $\ k\ne9\ ,$ then since there's a valid sequence of length $30$ leading from $1$ to $1$, and a valid sequence of length $\ k\ $ leading from $1$ to $\ a(k)\ ,$ then there's a valid sequence of length $\ j\ $ leading from $1$ to $\ a(k)\ $.  Therefore, $\ a(j)\le a(k)\ .$   But the multiplicative order of $\ 2\ $ mod $99$ is $\ 30\ .$ Therefore $ 2^j\pmod{99}\equiv2^k\pmod{99}\ ,$ and $ 10\times2^j\pmod{99}\equiv10\times2^k\pmod{99}\ ,$ and $\ a(j)\ $ cannot be smaller than the smaller of these, which is just $\ a(k)\ .$ Therefore, $\ a(j)=a(k)\ .$
For $\ n\ge1\ $ $\ a(30n+9)=17\ ,$ since because there's a valid sequence of length $\ 39\ $ leading from $1$ to $17$$\,^{\color{red}{\dagger\dagger}}$ and a valid sequence of length  $30$ leading from $1$ to $1$, then repeating the latter sequence $\ n-1\ $ times, followed by the former produces a sequence of length.  $\ 30n+9\ $ leading from $1$ to $17.$  Therefore $\ a(30n+9)\le17\ .$  But $\ 17\equiv2^{30n+9}\pmod{99}\ $ and $\ 71\equiv10\times2^{30n+9}\pmod{99}\ ,$ so $\ a(30n+9)\ $ can't be smaller than $17.$ Therefore $\ a(30n+9)=17\ .$
\begin{array}{|c|cccccccc|c|c|c|}
\hline
{\ \\k}&&&&&&&&&{\hspace{0.3em}a(k)\\\text{upper}\\ \text{bound}}&{\hspace{0.3em}2^k\\\text{mod}\\99}&{2^k10\\\text{mod}\\99}\\
\hline
0&1\\
1&2&&&&&&&&2&2&20\\
2&4&&&&&&&&4&4&40\\
3&8&&&&&&&&8&8&80\\
4&16&&&61&&&&&16&16&61\\
5&23&32&&122&&&&&23&32&23\\
6&46&64&&244&&&&&46&64&46\\
7&29&128&&488&92&&&& 29&29&92\\
8&58&256&85&976&184&&&&58&58&85\\
9&&215&71&2591&368&&&&71&17&71\\
10&&34&&2815&736&&&&34&34&43\\
11&&68&&365&2741&&&&68&68&86\\
12&&37&&730&2845&&&&37&37&73\\
13&&47&&1460&965&74&&&47&74&47\\
14&&49&&2920&391&841&148&&49&49&94\\
15&&89&&485&287&2861&296&98&89&98&89\\
16&&&&79&475&2275&295&196&79&97&79\\
17&&&&&59&4550&95&392&59&95&59\\
18&&&&&&19&91&487&19&91&19\\
19&&&&&&38&281&479&38&83&38\\
20&&&&&&67&265&859&67&67&76\\
21&&&&&&&35&1718&35&35&53\\
22&&&&&&&7&3436&7&70&7\\
23&&&&&&&14&2786&14&41&14\\
24&&&&&&&28&2755&28&82&28\\
25&&&&&&&56&155&56&65&56\\
26&&&&&&&&13&13&31&13\\
27&&&&&&&&26&26&62&26\\
28&&&&&&&&25&25&25&52\\
29&&&&&&&&5&5&50&5\\
30&&&&&&&&1&1&1&1\\
\hline
\end{array}
Proof of the key observation
If  $\ x=\sum_\limits{i=0}^r10^ix_i\ ,$ where $\ x_0,x_1,\dots,x_r\ $ are the decimal digits of $\ x\ ,$ then
\begin{align}
x&\equiv\sum_\limits{i=0}^rx_i\pmod{9}\\
&\equiv\sum_\limits{i=0}^rx_i10^{r-i}\pmod{9}\\
&\equiv R(x)\pmod{9}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, if $\ y\ $ is the successor of $\ x\ $ in a valid sequence starting from $1,$ then either $\ y=2x\equiv2x\pmod{9}\ $ or $\ y=R(2x)\equiv2x\pmod{9}\ ,$ so, in either case $\ y\equiv2x\pmod{9}\ .$ It follows by induction that if $\ y\ $ is the last term in a valid sequence of  length $\ k ,$ then $\ y\equiv2^k\pmod{9}\ .$
Also
\begin{align}
x&\equiv\sum_\limits{i=0}^r(-1)^ix_i\pmod{11}\\
&\equiv(-1)^r\sum_\limits{i=0}^rx_i10^{r-i}\pmod{11}\\
&\equiv(-1)^rR(x)\pmod{11}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, either $\ x\equiv R(x)\pmod{11}\ $ or $\ x\equiv-R(x)\pmod{11}\ ,$ and if $\ y\ $ is the successor of $\ x\ $ in a valid sequence starting from $1$, then either $\ y\equiv2x\pmod{11}\ $ or $\ y\equiv-2x\pmod{11}\ .$  Again it follows by induction that if $\ y\ $ is the last term in a valid sequence of  length $\ k ,$ then either $\ y\equiv2^k\pmod{11}\ $ or $\ y\equiv-2^k\pmod{11}\ .$ Since $\ 10\equiv1\pmod{9}\ $ and $\ 10\equiv-1\pmod{11}\ ,$ it follows from the Chinese remainder theorem that either $\ y\equiv2^k\pmod{99}\ $ or $\ y\equiv10\times2^k\pmod{99}\ .$ Since $\ a(k)\ $ must be the last term in a sequence of length $\ k\ $ starting from $1$ it follows that either $\ a(k)\equiv2^k\pmod{99}\ $ or $\ a(k)\equiv10\times2^k\pmod{99}\ .$
$\,^\color{red}{\dagger}$ Namely,
\begin{align}
 &71, 116, 170, 215, 269, 368, 512, 611,\\
 &863, 962, 1304, 1358, 1952, 2294, 2591, 3284,\\
 &3536, 4031, 4823, 4922, 6353, 8531, 17342, 24371
\end{align}
$\,^{\color{red}{\dagger\dagger}}$ Found by David A. Corneth and posted on April 25 to the OEIS page cited by the OP.

You have provided the data to show the values are eventually periodic.  First look at the values of $k$ such that $a(k)=1$.  These are at least all $k$ such that $k \equiv 0 \pmod {30}$.  If there are any other values of $k$, take the $\gcd$ of all those values, which must be a factor of $30$.  $1$ will eventually recur at this $\gcd$.  Once the recurrences of $1$ are established, consider the sequence of values in a cycle between the $1$s.  Each value is no higher than the corresponding value in the previous cycle.  If any value is reduced, it must come from a $1$ before.  That position in the cycle cannot increase.  Eventually we must hit a minimum at each position and that cycle will repeat forever.

Ohhhhh, actually, this is correct. I finally understood it. Subsequences $b_n = a({30n + k})$ must be monotonically decreasing. I initially misunderstood your proof, sorry

I am using the relation you quote $a(k) \le a(k \mod 30)$.  There are only finitely many sequences of $30$ numbers less that the first $30\ a(k)$  If you ever achieve a lower value for some $a(k)$ than this you can achieve it every $30$ positions upward.  At the extreme, if you ever achieve $a(k)=1$ for some $k$ coprime to $30$, call it $m$,  the sequence will eventually become constant at $1$ for all $k$ because you can express every large enough number as a sum of $30$s and $m$s.
